# XML Schema: Child element type based attribute value?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.0

I am trying to make a schema where the type of an element is determined by the value of a parent's attribute. In particular, want I want to do is this

```
<argument name="foo" type="float">5.6</argument>
```

where the value of the argument should be enforced to conform with a floating point value. So that the type of the value element is of the type defined by the attribute of the `argument`   element.

Now, I found an [older post on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545825/xml-schema-restrict-child-element-based-on-attribute-value-of-parent-element) where it was stated that this cannot be done in XML-Schema 1.0.

So my question is; **Is there a recommended alternate way to do it**? The closest I can think of is allowing something like

```
<argument name="foo">
    <float>5.6</float>
</argument>
```

Letting `argument` contain an element of the type `type` and then let `float` be derived from `type`.

Comment: `<floatArgument name="foo">5.6</floatArgument>`?

Answer (score 2):

Depends what you mean by "an alternate way". You can change your document design (e.g. to use xsi:type), you can use a different validation methodology (e.g. RelaxNG or Schematron), or you can move to XSD 1.1.